# jQuery datetime picker set year range

Tags: jquery, datepicker

good day. I downloaded a jQuery plugin [here](https://plugins.jquery.com/datetimepicker/2.3.6/) to have a dateTime picker but I want to change the range from 1900 - current year right now. I tried using the

```
minDate and maxDate
```

but doesn't work. I also tried using this codes

```
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
yearRange:'1900:' + new Date().getFullYear()
```

but nothing keeps working and still throws me to the range 1950 - 2050. thanks

**UPDATE**

ok so my code and the code posted was correct. it was throwing the year due to a command in the `jquery.datetimepicker.full.js` wherein the

```
    yearStart: 1950,
    yearEnd: 2050,
```

was set to this. I simply changed it to this

```
    yearStart: 1900,
    yearEnd: new Date().getFullYear(),
```

Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: create a demo to show what you are having in snippet `<>`

Comment: im sorry but how to do that? sorry im really new here.im just curious why isn't it working in my codes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add **YearRange** as shown below.it will works..

```
$('#dtp').datepicker({
dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
yearRange: "-100:+50",
autoSize: true                            
});
```

or

```html
<html lang = "en">
   <head>
      <meta charset = "utf-8">
      <title>jQuery UI Datepicker functionality</title>
      <link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"
         rel = "stylesheet">
      <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      
      <!-- Javascript -->
      <script>
         $(function() {
            $( "#datepicker-13" ).datepicker({
              dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
              changeMonth: true,
              changeYear: true,
              yearRange:'1900:' + new Date().getFullYear(),
              autoSize: true                            
            });

            $( "#datepicker-13" ).datepicker("show");
         });
      </script>
   </head>
   
   <body>
      <!-- HTML --> 
      <p>Enter Date: <input type = "text" id = "datepicker-13"></p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi sir. i have updated my question and listed the solution that i made. it was not in our code but was in the plug-in i downloaded. i simply change it to the answer above. thanks again sir

Comment: i think that's not a correct solution. Editing plugin is not at an healthy behavior. You can override those properties in your code.

Comment: how can i override the plug-in sir?

Comment: you can run the code snippet above it is working as you suggested without having any edits in the plugin

Comment: i already tried sr but the code doesn't work. Even the datetime picker doesn't pop up properly

Comment: If you need just a date picker you can use my code. Here no need of additional plugins.